# language detector

Tags: java, nlp

I want a java code which reads a text inside a document and say that it is in which language (English, Spanish, ...). The format of the document is not important. I want the output to be for example : "This document is in Spanish". Please guide me in this way and give me a sample code for it.

Comment: Most document formats embed that information in their metadata. For plain text files, yes, you'll have to do some magic.

Comment: This is Questions & Answers site, so what is your question and I recommend to read the FAQ...

Comment: You need to use a guess based on the words used.  I would create a dictionary of words for each language and try to match them.  Note: some short documents could be either.

Comment: See [The WiLI benchmark dataset for written language identification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07779.pdf), especially Figure 3.

Answer (score 3):

i would use google translator's api
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/using_rest_langdetect.html

Comment: *"**Note:** The Google Language Detect API must be used for user-generated language detection. Automated or batched queries of any kind are strictly prohibited."*

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to build n-gram models for your candidate languages, then build a similar model for the target document, and compare against the reference models using a simple editing distance calculation. Gertjan van Noord's site http://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/TextCat/competitors.html has links to several libraries you could use.

Answer (score 0):

The [language-detection](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) library is quite simple to use in Java (see sample code) and robust. Detect at least 53 languages from a wide variety of families.